React front-end application on Azure stops working after browser refresh
I have a front-end application developed in React, deployed on Azure Static Web App. In one of the environments, the application renders a specific screen correctly when accessed. However, if I refresh the browser (F5), the screen no longer renders (this issue occurs on some screens, but not others), and an error message appears in the browser console:
Error: Minified React error #301; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=301
According to the React documentation (link above), this error means: "Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop."
Oddly, the same code (same branch) deployed on another Static Web App in Azure (different URL) works perfectly fine after refreshing, with no issues whatsoever.
After the F5 refresh, I can only access the screen again after clearing the browser cache. Once the cache is cleared, the screen loads correctly, I can navigate to other routes, return to the same routes, but the issue reappears if I hit F5 again (this issue occurs on some screens, but not others).
Does anyone have any ideas on what might be causing this?
Additional Information:

Deployment in both environments is done through Azure Pipelines via
Azure DevOps.
The same code (same branch) is deployed in two
different environments (two different URLs), with different behaviors
after the F5 refresh.
The Azure Static Web App configurations are
identical (there’s not much to configure in this Azure service, I'm
using the basic hosting option for this service).



if I refresh the browser (F5), the screen no longer renders

The cause of the issue could be that you haven't configured the fallbackroutes  in the staticwebapp.config.json file. It can cause the Urls don't work after refreshing.
Refer to this doc: Fallback routes

These client-side routing rules update the browser's window location without making requests back to the server. If you refresh the page, or go directly to URLs generated by client-side routing rules, a server-side fallback route is required to serve the appropriate HTML page. The fallback page is often designated as index.html for your client-side app.

Here is an example:
{
  "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "/index.html",
    "exclude": ["/images/*.{png,jpg,gif}", "/css/*"]
  }
}

Note: You need to add staticwebapp.config.json file at the root folder of your react app.

I have a staticwebapp.config.json file with fallbackroutes configured. The system works fine in one environment (using the same code and configuration) when pressing F5 (all screens). However, in the environment where it's not working properly, the issue only occurs on some screens when pressing F5, not all of them.

Based on your description, are you encountering any error message when deploying via azure devops? If no, it should be more related to azure static web app configuration. You can add the addition azure static web app tag to your question.

No, the error does not occur during deployment. Regarding the configuration in Azure Staic Web App, I don't see many configuration options, but I have already compared the options between the environment where everything works fine and the environment where it doesn't, everything is ok (the same between the environments).
Anyway, thanks for the suggestion, I just added the Azure Static Web App tag to the question.
